# Auxiliary verb reduction in not only - but also structure

Tags: tenses, auxiliary-verbs

I was wondering if it is correct to reduce the auxiliary verb of a *not only - but also* sentence that has multiple clauses sharing that same auxiliary verb, for example:

Not only did I finish my homework, not only did I exercise, not only did I play some video game, but I also cleaned the house.

Can we say:

Not only did I finish my homework, exercise, play some video game, but I also cleaned the house.

Or should we use past-tense verbs for the clauses in the middle?

Not only did I finish my homework, exercised, played some video game, but I also cleaned the house.

Thank you.

Comment: The crucial point (as DW points out) is that the verb(s) following auxiliary "do" must be in the plain form, so "Not only did I finish my homework, exercise, play some video game, ....  is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straightforward case of coordination at the level of complement to the auxiliary verb. The subject *I*, auxiliary verb *did*, and modifier *not only* apply to all three elements in the coordination. The elements in the coordination are plain infinitivals acting as complements to *did*.

> Not only did I
>
> [finish my homework, exercise, play some video games],
>
> but I also cleaned the house.

Examples of similar constructions are readily found.

> Nor did either Wiener or Humphrey's Executor suggest that Congress
> could not only **create** the independent agency , **specify** its duties, and
> **control** the grounds for removal of its members but could also itself
> appoint or remove them without the participation of the Executive
> Branch of the Government. (Supreme Court Opinion,     BUCKLEY v. VALEO,
> 424 U.S. 1)
>
> The issue on which we all seem to agree is that self-interest and the
> common good are two sides of the same coin, and that to survive as a
> sustainable planet we must not only **create** wealth , **develop** skill and
> talent, but ensure that no one is left behind.(International
> Development White Paper, Hansard, 3 may 2001)
>
> When he preached, Thomas became wholly a man; not only did he **laugh** ,
> **crack** jokes, **sing** and **shimmy** on the pulpit, but his severe stammer
> left him completely. (    Order and disorder on Smith Island;  Sheehan, Kevin)
>
> Not only did he **write** , **produce** and **play** on some of the most popular
> and influential songs of the disco era for Chic, Sister Sledge and
> Diana Ross alongside his fellow New Yorker, Bernard Edwards, but he
> has also created hit records for an eclectic array of artists,
> including Madonna, David Bowie, Deborah Harry, Duran Duran, Mick
> Jagger, Al Jarreau, Jeff Beck, INXS and the B-52s. (  CLASSIC TRACKS: Chic 'Le Freak' | - [Sound On Sound](http://%20%09CLASSIC%20TRACKS:%20Chic%20%27Le%20Freak%27%20%7C%20-%20Sound%20On%20Sound))

As is clear from these examples, all verbs in the coordination have the same inflection.

Comment: Perfect! Very clear explanation. Much appreciated, DW256.